# How to use 'sample_weight' in keras

Tags: python, keras

I want to implement Deep RL policy gradient. For that it is required to specify how much weight each sample in a batch should have in computing the total loss.
My problem is I could not assign weight to each row of the record.

```
state:  [[ 0.02148486  0.00763404 -0.0333062  -0.04380627]]
action:  [[1. 0.]]
discounted_r.shape:  [[1]]
```

The error message is:
ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (1, 1). In order to use time step-wise sample weights, you should specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile(). If you just mean to use sample-wise weights, make sure your sample_weight array is 1D.
Could you help me to solve this error.

```
import numpy as np
import gym
from collections import deque
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.optimizers import Adam
    from keras.models import Model, load_model
    import numpy as np
    import random
    
    def DeepNNModel():
        model  = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(64, input_dim = 4, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(2))
        model.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3))
        print(model.summary())
        return model
    
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
    model = DeepNNModel()
    state = env.reset()
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, 4])
    
    action = np.zeros([2])
    action[0] = 1
    action = np.reshape(action, [1, 2])
    print ("state: ", state)
    print ("action: ", action)
    
    discounted_r = arr = np.array([ [1] ])
    print ("discounted_r.shape: ", discounted_r)
    print ("action.shape: ", action.shape)
    
    #model.fit(state, action, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    model.fit(state, action, sample_weight=discounted_r, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

Comment: Your error message is indicating that `discounted_r` is not a 1D array. It has shape `(1,2)`, which in the world of numpy arrays is 2D. A 1D array would have shape `(2,)`. You can squeeze out the extra dimension with `np.squeeze(discounted_r)` and it will be reduced to 1D.

Comment: I have replaced "discounted_r = np.reshape(discounted_r, [1, 2])" with "discounted_r = np.squeeze(discounted_r)". Now the error message is: ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (2,) for an input with shape (1, 2). sample_weight cannot be broadcast. If I not wrong, I think that since weight is a single value assigned to single row of the action. but this i cannot do it.

Comment: I don't actually know keras -- just making guesses based on the error message. What about squeezing  `action` to shape `(2,)`  as well? Is there a reason you're defining your state, action and weight arrays as 2D arrays? Why are you reshaping to `[1,4]` and `[1,2]`? this makes them 2D arrays.